How do you define functions acting on sets if the set of all sets is a paradox?
Generally, functions are defined as taking an input from one set and providing an output from another set. For example, if I wanted a function that took the average of two integers, I would write it as
$$f(x,y):\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q} = \frac{x+y}{2},$$
where for two sets $A$ and $B$, $A\times B = \{(a,b)\,|\, a\in A \land b\in B\}$. As another example, a function that rounds a real number to the nearest integer could be written as
$$f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z} = \lfloor x+0.5\rfloor.$$
In both cases, the input and output are both sets; and if you define $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R},$  and ordered pairs set-theoretically they're all sets of sets too. But what if you have a function that acts on sets in general, for example $\cap$ (intersection), $\cup$ (union) or $\times$ (Cartesian product)? Since the set of all sets cannot exist, from what sets do these functions take inputs or outputs?
(I also know there's a set-theoretical definition of what a function itself is, but constructing that set for a given function would still require having sets for the input and output possiblities... am I missing something?)
Thanks for your help!

Good question. I guess technically those functions are maps of classes, not maps of sets. The ZFC set theory axioms ensure the existence of $\cap, \cup$, power sets, and so forth. So thinking of these functions in the typical set-theoretic sense of a function would be circular.

When you say in these examples the input and output are sets, you actually mean the domain and codomain are sets. When they're proper classes, you have class functions such as $\bigcup$.

This is a good question. As you note, "intersection" can't be a function whose domain is the set of ordered pairs of sets, since the set of all sets is not a set.
The solution to the paradox is that $A \cap B$ is defined only for known sets $A$ and $B$.
In everyday mathematics you don't have to worry about this. It's an issue only when you are explicitly thinking about foundations.

So if you were trying to define the intersection function, would you define it separately for different instances you need it for (defining it once for sets of real numbers, defining it once for sets of ordered pairs of real numbers, etc.)? Or is it just undefinable and in a situation where you need it you can explicitly use set-builder notation? Sorry if these are dumb questions.

@Mathemagician314 You define the intersection   $A \cap B$ abstractly under the assumption that $A$ and $B$ have already been proved to be sets. That covers everything you need to do everyday mathematics, since the integers, reals, etc. are constructed in a way that tells you they are sets. So any use of set builder notation is acceptable. (Not dumb questions, but questions you can postpone knowing the answers to.)

Great, thank you so much!
